# Create a binary variable based on a condition over two consecutive rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I would like to create a binary variable (GH), if BP1 variable is >= 140 OR/AND BP2 variable is >= 90, on two or more consecutive rows for each ID.

This is my data:

```
ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
BP1 <- c(130, 140, 140, 130, 110, 120, 130)
BP2 <- c(80, 90, 80, 110, 90, 80, 90)
DF1 <- data.frame(ID, BP1, BP2)
```

[image: DF1]

This is what I would like the data to look like:

[image: DF2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a custom function which compares a value and it's `lag` to a number and returns a logical. Then used that function to check if two consecutive rows have the condition you described in each `ID`.

```r
library(dplyr)

lag_comp <- function(xcol, n){xcol >= n & lag(xcol, default = 0) >= n}

DF1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(GH = +(sum(lag_comp(BP1, 140) | lag_comp(BP2, 90)) > 0))

#> # A tibble: 7 x 4
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>      ID   BP1   BP2    GH
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1     1   130    80     1
#> 2     1   140    90     1
#> 3     1   140    80     1
#> 4     1   130   110     1
#> 5     2   110    90     0
#> 6     2   120    80     0
#> 7     2   130    90     0
```

Answer (score 1):

`group_by(ID)`, then add the binary  variable `gh` by adding `1` if there are 2 consecutive rows fulfilling the conditions, then check, if the sum per group is `0` - if yes make this group `0`, too and the other `1`.

```
DF1 |>
  group_by(ID) |>
  mutate(gh = ifelse(
    ((BP1 >= 140 & lead(BP1) >= 140) |
      (BP2 >= 90 & lead(BP2) >= 90)), 1, 0
  ))  |> 
  mutate(gh = ifelse(sum(gh, na.rm=T)==0, 0, 1))

# A tibble: 7 × 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
#     ID   BP1   BP2    gh
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1   130    80     1
#2     1   140    90     1
#3     1   140    80     1
#4     1   130   110     1
#5     2   110    90     0
#6     2   120    80     0
#7     2   130    90     0
```